# 95% of apps in Office Marketplace are grayed out (Unknown capability with ID='SupportedLocales')

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

We have successfully configured the environment for deploying apps in a SharePoint 2013 on-premises installation, and have installed a couple of apps (Corporate News App and Resource Reservation) without problems from the Office Marketplace.

But only a small percentage of the apps are shown as available to install, the big majority, around 95%, are grayed out and when clicking on it to install, the page that loads has this message:

> Sorry, this application is not compatible with the server.

Looking in the logs, we have found that in a lot of apps, Sharepoint writes this record  everytime we open the app page in the Marketplace:

> Prerequisites Checking for App '[App Name Here]' failed:  Unknown
>   capability with ID='SupportedLocales', name='Configuraciones
>   regionales admitidas', version='' is not available.

Both Windows Server and SharePoint language is Spanish.

Answer (score -1):

Problem resolved, I just needed to install the English language.